# What API would initiate an FTP transfer and report status to a GUI?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, ftp

Thinking of something like an MFC application, with one button - "Download"

- User selects download and then is prompted for the location of where the file will be saved.
- Connects to the remote ftp server (login, ip, file to GET all hard coded)
- Displays a status bar of how much of the file has been downloaded.

Which Windows API would best support this entire application in C or C++? (looking to keep it as simple and straightforward as possible)

Comment: "Basic functions"? You just described an entire application.

Comment: For the FTP bits, you want WinInet: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385331.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - User selects download and then is prompted for the location of where the file will be saved.

You've got the [Common File Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for that.  MFC has a wrapper.

> - Connects to the remote ftp server (login, ip, file to GET all hard coded)

There's the WinInet API, which includes function such as [`FtpGetFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384157%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

> - Displays a status bar of how much of the file has been downloaded.

If you need to report progress, use [`FtpOpenFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384166%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead and read chunks using `InternetReadFile`.  Windows progress bars are created with `CreateWindow` and controlled with `SendMessage`.

Comment: MFC has a wrapper for progress bars, too: [CProgressCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sys15k39(v=VS.100).aspx)

Comment: If you're on Vista or newer, you can use `TaskDialogEx`, which has support for progress bars.